# How to update the directive when the parent's scope variable changes?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

```
Directive:
<div ng-show="{{ show }}">
        ...
</div>

angular.module('mymodule').directive('mydirective', [
  function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            show: '='
        },
        ...
    };
}]);

Parent:
<div mydirective show="show" ng-repeat="item in items">
</div>

controller.js:
this.show = false //intially

function changeVisibility(){
  this.show = true; //how to tell the directive about this change?
}
```

"show" is a scope variable that is initially false, but later turns to true. However, the directive's scope variable "show" does not get updated when this happens. How do I update the directive's show variable when the parent's show variable changes? Do I need to a $scope.$watch or something?

Comment: give `$scope.$apply()` a shot! http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html

Comment: @spoonscen `$scope.$apply()` is a not a *"cure all"* and shouldn't be used unless scope is changed outside angular context which is clearly not the case here

Answer (score 0):

`ng-show` expects an expression not interpolation

Try

```
ng-show="show"
```

Comment: That part actually works. I have a controllerAs which is why I'm using controller.show. Will update the question.

Comment: oh...also note don't think you can use an isolated scope directive on `ng-repeat` element. Your edit is not a [mcve]. Create a simple plunker that reproduces issue